# Only defined colums send via data from google sheets per E-Mail as pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hope anyone can help me, since I am really new to this and I am not able to get it working.

I have an google sheet with colums from A-F, I have no problem sending the whole sheet as PDF with the script below, but I only want to send colums A, C and F as PDF. How do I do that?

```
function email() {
  var message = {
    to: "x...@xxx.com",
    subject: "xxx",
    body: "xx Mr.xx",
    name: "Mr.xx",
    replyTo: "xx.xx",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("xx.pdf")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- From your script and `I have an google sheet with columns from A-F,`, in this case, you have a Google Spreadsheet including only one sheet which has the data in the columns "A" to "F".
- You want to export the columns "A", "C" and "F" from the sheet as a PDF data.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, how about the following flow?

  1. Hide the columns except for the columns "A", "C" and "F".
  2. Export the sheet as a PDF data.
  3. Show all columns.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function email() {
  const retrieveColumns = [1, 3, 6]; // The column numbers of 1, 3, and 6 are A, C and F, respectively.
  
  // 1. Hide the columns except for the columns "A", "C" and "F".
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const maxColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  for (let c = 1; c <= maxColumn; c++) {
    if (!retrieveColumns.includes(c)) sheet.hideColumns(c);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // 2. Export the sheet as a PDF data.
  const blob = ss.getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("xx.pdf");  // This is the same with ss.getBlob().setName("xx.pdf")
  
  // 3. Show all columns.
  sheet.showColumns(1, maxColumn);

  var message = {
    to: "x...@xxx.com",
    subject: "xxx",
    body: "xx Mr.xx",
    name: "Mr.xx",
    replyTo: "xx.xx",
    attachments: [blob]
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

#### Note:

- If my understanding for your situation was not correct and when your Spreadsheet has multiple sheets and you want to export the specific sheet by selecting the columns, please tell me.

#### References:

- [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)
- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved the issue, ありがとうございます!!

Comment: @Manuel Kapal Thank you for your response.